# apt-get : no installation candidate for libxul-dev

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, apt, package-management

When I'm installing `libxul-dev` I end with this error message:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libxul-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree      
Reading state information... Done
Package libxul-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package libxul-dev has no installation candidate
```

How can I solve this?

[sources.list](http://pastebin.com/SA6CfQ05)

Comment: I used [this](http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/) generator to clean it a little.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the [list of files in the `libxul-dev` in hardy](http://packages.ubuntu.com/hardy/all/libxul-dev/filelist). Look for the [package containing](http://packages.ubuntu.com/#keyword), say, [`libxul.so`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?mode=exactfilename&suite=lucid&section=all&arch=any&searchon=contents&keywords=libxul.so). In more recent releases, the corresponding package is [`xulrunner-1.9.2-dev`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/xulrunner-1.9.2-dev) (the version number might change). So, if you have old compilation instructions that mention `libxul-dev`, try with `xulrunner*-dev` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The `libxul-dev` package seems to be only available to **hardy**.  Sorry, this was my fault in the other question, [I spotted it here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libxul-dev) but paid too little attention to detail.  And the [`sugar-hulahop` package was apparently deleted from the repositories, too](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/packages/show/193723).

I don't know any easy way go get these things (`hulahop` and `libxul` and maybe further dependencies) on Ubuntu apart from "the manual way".  [Here someone suggests using Debian's repos, I don't know how feasible that is.](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1467805)

Comment: I have found [this](http://launchpadlibrarian.net/17059689/libxul-dev_1.8.1.16%2Bnobinonly-0ubuntu1_all.deb) debian package from [this](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/lucid/i386/libxul-dev/1.8.1.16+nobinonly-0ubuntu1) page but it has dependency problems. I'm afraid that when I will download deb packages for all dependencies every of them will have another dependencies so it will endless process :-( There is no other way?